# when i click a button in ios app i want the image to change

Tags: ios, uibutton

the title much explains it really in my button

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender
```

when the button is clicked i want ti to swap images from a small grey icon to a green icon
im trying it this way but i cant seem to get it to work

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [senderButton setImage :@"liked.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
{
```

Has Any body any ideas how this can be done at the  moment the image is selected in the xcode control panel and is named likebtn.png and need it changing to liked.png after clicked

Comment: You're close except you need to pass a `UIImage`, not an `NSString` for the image parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the image properly added to your project, and it's a png:

```
- (IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
[senderButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liked"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

PS: Are you sure you wish to set the image for the selected state? If not, use `UIControlStateNormal` instead.

Comment: how do i add an image file as a property?

Comment: @Mike J Aspinall Maybe I did not get you, but not sure why you'd want to do that. What do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setImage in viewDidLoad when creating button:

```
[LikeBtn setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Maddy says about passing a UIImage rather than a string for a selected state, you will also need to declare that the button is now selected. If you change your code to this, it should work for you

```
-(IBAction)LikeBtn:(id)sender {

    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [senderButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

   senderButton.selected = YES;
```

}

You can also put a `if (senderButton.selected)` condition within the IBAction method to detect and toggle between button states, changing the state from YES to NO.

Hope this helps